# Difference between "I am really sorry" and "I really am sorry"

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, meaning-in-context, adverb-position

I know they are slightly different, but I can't tell how.

I've read about the usage of the word "really" [in a negative sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169838/really-in-a-negative-sentence). But it didn't tell me about how the position of the word "really" can affect the meaning in a positive sentence.

I've heard sentences I'm confused about:

- I **am really** sorry
- I **really am** sorry

And these are the ones I've made up myself (I don't know if this kind of sentence exists):

- She **can be really** persuasive
- She **really can be** persuasive

How do I tell them apart (the grammatical structure)? Are they different in meaning too? How?

Comment: In short: in first case *really* serves as an adjective meaning *very*.  In second case, *really* means *truly*, and serves as an adverb.

Comment: @Ben has penetrated to the truth of this matter.

Comment: @Ben Voigt \\ "Really" is an adverb in both instances.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi: Oh right, because *sorry* is itself a predicate-adjective.  So of course it needs an adverb to modify it.

Comment: "I really *am* sorry" and "She really *can* be persuasive", if spoken with that emphasis, would mean that there is some doubt about the truth of these statements and the speaker wants to remove it.

Comment: "Really am" asserts sincerity; "really sorry" asserts intensity.

Comment: I think this belongs on ELL.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In 'I am really sorry', *really* is an intensifier. You can replace it with *very*.

'I really am sorry' is a reassurance: you are not saying how sorry you are, just that you are *definitely* sorry.

Comment: In the second case, you can't replace *really* with *very*.

Comment: But in both instances, you could replace them with *truly*.

Comment: it would change the meaning of the first one if you changed it to _truly_; both sentences would mean the same

Comment: @DLeh no, replacing "I am really sorry" with "I am truly sorry" still operates as an intensifier.

Comment: @bib **Why not both??** '*I really am truly sorry.*'

Comment: @Josh What you really mean is *I truly really am really truly very sorry!*

Comment: @bib I think that's what I *really truly meant* actually.

Answer (score 27):

"I am really sorry" means "I am sorry to a greater extent than if I said, 'I am sorry'"

The 'really' modifies 'sorry' and acts as a general intensifier.

---

"I really am sorry" means "I am sorry with a greater sincerity than if I said, 'I am sorry'"

The 'really' modifies 'am' and clarifies that the speaker is not being sarcastic or shallow.

---

"She can be (really persuasive)" = "She can be highly persuasive"

"She (really can) be persuasive" = "She certainly can be persuasive"

Comment: +1 The general rule is that you want the modifier as close as possible to the word it modifies to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: No, in 'I really am sorry', 'really' 'modifies' the whole statement. It is a modal (ie adding a comment about the truth value of the statement)  pragmatic marker. It could be put to the end: 'I am sorry. _Really!_'

Comment: @Edwin: I really don't think so (i.e. - I *definitely* disagree). If on the other hand I'd said *I don't think so, really* (or put *really* at the start), it would not only apply to the *whole* statement - it would actually actually tend to *weaken* the assertion, not strengthen it.

Comment: @FF Is your first sentence an example or a comment?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Both, I think.

Comment: In 'I am cold / sorry / here / the Prime Minister', _be_ is a link verb: it doesn't make sense to talk about 'modifying' it (ie it doesn't accept adverbials). The usage of 'really' as a modal pragmatic marker is mentioned (and this sort of usage expanded upon) by [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_modal_adverbs) (though they use the traditional term 'modal adverb'): 'Modal adverbs are used to express the speaker's view of the truth value of a proposition (a clause or sentence) with which it is associated.' ...

Comment: With "I really am sorry", the usage is indeterminate between 'I am really (= very) sorry' and 'I'm sorry: really I am'. This is often the case for medial positioning of words that double as degree modifiers and pragmatic markers. I was addressing the pragmatic marker usage in my first comment, in line with user80584's answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The definition given in Wikipedia doesn't fit your claim. It says the modal adverb also modifies an adjective or adverb. In "I really am sorry," the modal adverb does not modify sorry, or else it would mean the same thing as "I am really sorry." As far as I can tell, the actual issue is that "is" and "can be" are modal verbs, and a modal adverb can modify a modal verb (despite no such claim in the Wikipedia article). In doing so, it modifies the modality of the verb, which in turn modifies the modality of the entire clause or sentence.

Comment: @trikly (1) "I really am sorry ..." is often used where "I honestly am sorry ..." would not be considered. This virtually confirms emphasiser usage (in those cases). Of course, the modal usage is not impossible: ... "Peter! Why haven't you phoned your sister to cheer her up after her dog died?" ... "It's just that I've been so busy. I really am sorry, you know." (2) _Be_ is not a modal verb.

Answer (score 6):

Complex sentences can have modifiers whose meaning is ambiguous, and as a rule of thumb, in those cases, you should assume that any modifier is modifying the next word or phrase that makes sense. To illustrate, I'll just emphasize the modifier and the next word, as this is usually enough:

> I am *really sorry*.

This sentence has the same meaning as *I am sorry*. The word **really** acts as an **intensifier**, indicating the *degree* to which he or she is sorry.

Someone may use the word in this way to indicate to the listener they realize what they have done is not a small thing, something that a simple apology may not be able to fix. You can swap the word **really** with another intensifier and get the same effect:

> I am *very sorry*.

... has exactly the same meaning. Whereas:

> I *really am* sorry.

If you follow the same logic as the first sentence, the word **really** is placed before **am** to emphasize that the speaker is truly in the state of being sorry. With the placement of the intensifier, the speaker is drawing attention to the fact that *he or she is sorry* over *the degree to which he or she is sorry*.

Someone may use the word in this way when they are trying to indicate that they *are* sorry, and how sorry they are is not as important as making sure the listener knows they are sorry. It may be indicating that this statement is *sincere*, not sarcastic or patronizing.

The difference between the two sentences might be even easier to understand if we were to combine the two sentences:

> I *really* am *very* sorry.

In this case, not only is the speaker indicating sincerity ("*really am*") but also the degree to which he or she is sorry ("*very*" or "*really sorry*").

I also should note that this is assuming two native English speakers in dialogue. If one were speaking to a foreigner or a child, he or she may interpret both sentences the same depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

A co-worker says "I am really sorry; for not giving you credit for your idea during our business meeting"

The offended co-worker says; "Are you really? This seems to happen a lot with you"

The first co-worker says "I really am sorry; I hope you can forgive me!"

Note: the first occurrence is a "statement"; while, the second occurrence is a pleading; completely differing intents.

Answer (score -3):

"I am really sorry" is a phrase which you use to emphasize the truth that you feel truly bad for happening. While "I really am sorry" is grammatically incorrect and should not be used.

Comment: They are both grammatically correct.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! This isn't correct, I'm afraid. One might say "I really am tanned" to assert that the summer holiday had some sort of effect. That's different to "I am really tanned" which means the holiday was very sunny and resulted in a deep tan.